# "Using US-English keyboard with US-English codepage [437}

Tags: keyboard

I formatted a USB stick and installed the ubuntu pkg on it using rufus.  Set both my Dells (1 PC, 1 laptop) to boot the USB stick.  Both machines pop up with this message, then go to a C prompt.  How do I get to the ubuntu install?

Comment: Looks like you installed DOS onto your USB, instead of Ubuntu. Please make sure you follow [this guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows). By the time you press the 'Start' button, the dropdown next to 'Create a bootable disk using' should say 'ISO Image'. If it still says DOS, then you didn't properly select an ISO, and you will end up with what you describe, which is a DOS bootable USB.